# Run xUnit test with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, xunit

I've created ASP.NET we app project and then I've created a test class - this class is part of the .NET core.

I need to run the test by the console but I can't use .net core. because the app has to be compiled, etc. with MSBuild, so I have been doing some research about how to run xUnit test inside MSBuild task.

I found this https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-msbuild#options.

So I installed `xunit.runner.msbuild.net452.dll` but I cannot run the test.

```
error : System.InvalidOperationException: Unknown test framework: could not find xunit.dll (v1) or xunit.execution.*.dll .....
```

Is .NET framework is compatible with xUnit?

Comment: Seems like a pretty common error with a few environmental causes. What research have you done? You should share that research. At any rate, this is probably a better fit for https://sqa.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: i have been reading about xunit.runner.msbuild...but for the moment i am not being able to execute the tests. The last time i've luanched the msbuild command, the output was: AfterBuild:
  xUnit.net MSBuild Runner v2.4.1 (64-bit Desktop .NET 4.0.30319.42000). However, there is not way that i can know if the tests are done...

Comment: Clarification to questions should be done with an [edit] to the question itself. Comments can be deleted.